# How do I make an archive template for custom WooCommerce taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a new taxonomy for products on WooCommerce.
Now, when I go to the taxonomy view, it shows error 404.

How do I make it show the products just like in any other regular category on the site?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this code and it works for me.

I created a taxonomy name 'team' and here is my code.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'team_set_template');
function team_set_template( $template ){
  if(is_tax('team')) :
    $taxonomy = 'team';
    $term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
    $prod_term = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$term.''); 
    $term_slug = $prod_term[0]->slug;
    $t_id = $prod_term[0]->term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
    $term_meta['team_access_pin'];  

    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );

 else : 

    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );

 endif; 

}
```

Note:  I used this code in functions.php file.  If anyone wants to use this code. Please replace the name 'team' with your custom taxonomy name.

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: Thank you, Satya! This works!! In case of woocommerce, instead of 'archive-product.php', I inserted 'woocommerce.php' and the rest is taken care of by Woocommerce just like it would show its own 'categories' taxonomy.

Comment: Just a little note: make sure your custom taxonomy is registered as public true and query var true.

Comment: Also, if you use this in your functions.php only the archive-product.php template will be used sitewide. Instead, in the else, just return $template to utilize other templates you use.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs when WordPress does not find any template for the custom taxonomy.

1.The solution is to create a WooCommerce template named as "taxonomy-tax_name.php" (ideally in a child theme).
2.For this you could copy the contents of an archive template like archive-product.php and modify it by doing a WP_Query() with arguments for post_type=>"product" and add a "tax_query" with the newly made custom taxonomy slug.
3.This would get you the required products and now can be displayed as required.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new custom WooCommerce taxonomy you may need to refresh the WordPress permalink settings from:

**Admin Panel** -> **Settings** -> **Permalinks**

You only have to open the page and WordPress will refresh it automatically.

*Note:* Don't forget to clear the cache of your site if you are using a caching plugin!